# How to load my placeholder in case of failure to load url?

Tags: android, error-handling, drawable, android-drawable, android-glide

I'm trying to load an image using Glide.
I gave it a url however it results in a FileNotFound exception.
However this is not my concern, my concern is that I want to load a placeholder in case any of these errors occur.
I followed the guide to use glide, but nothing occurs.
Please take a look at my code.

I tried adding RequestListener and error fallback.

```
       Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url)      
       .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
       .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(placeholder))
       .error(Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(placeholder))
       .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(imageView);
```

I want my placeholder to be loading in my imageview.
Actual result is that my imageview is loaded with some placeholder not defined by me, something indicating that the image link is forbidden or something.
Expected: I want my placeholder to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer code below to show `placeholder` image in case of Error :

```
 Glide.with(context).load(BASE_URL + imageUrl)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                            .error(R.drawable.defaultimage)).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified code:

```
int placeholder = R.drawable.placeholder

Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .error(placeholder)
            .placeholder(placeholder)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: what are you using as placeholder? Also remove RequestListener if you are not using it and let me know how it goes

Comment: also try remove crossFade, if I remember correctly it might be also a problem

Comment: Rafz , my placeholder is a drawable in my resource folder

Comment: I understand that, try remove CrossFade or unnecessary RequestListener and it should work

Comment: I updated the answer. It should work, if not then maybe it is something wrong with your Drawable resource or ImageView it self?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int placeholder = R.drawable.error 
GlideApp.with(imageView.getContext())
          .load(url)
          .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(placeholder)
              .error(placeholder).dontTransform()
              .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
          .into(mImageView);
```

Comment: go to your `ImageView` in xml set the error `drawable` there. and check if you are able to see that `drawable` in layout preview. I understand you have some issue with your `ImageView` in xml.

Comment: now delete from there and set in Glide .. `Glide.load(R.drawable.error)` like this. and see if it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this-

```
.error(getResourses.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder))
```

instead of using this-

```
.error(Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(placeholder))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code below.

```
Glide.with(your context).load(imageurl).apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(your drawable here)).error(your error drawable).into(your imageview);
```

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try using RequestOptions

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .apply(requestOptions)
     .into(holder.imageView);
```